# What is pylint exit code 28?

Tags: pylint

Pylint exited with code 28 on Linux run. What does this error code mean?

I know it doesn't mean low on space as I tried the same command on a empty VM.

Answer (score 9):

**Answer + Examples:**

(Note the [pylint exit codes](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/run.html#exit-codes) table below from pylint official site.

pylint exit codes conforms to 2 to the power of x (x = 0 to 5)
This is a crystal clear sign that they use a binary system for exit codes, this means that (as mentioned in the example within the image below) if exit code is:

`28` - in binary: `0001 1100` (exit code 4, 8, 16 was triggered at least once for each)

`63` - in binary: `0011 1111` (all error codes was triggered at least once for each which is the maximum errors combined)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Pyline exit code 28 on Linux and exit code 30 on Windows both mean that the config file that you are feeding in has an invalid configuration.

For me that was having underscores separating words instead of dashes. I had changed this because the wheel build deprecated dashes for flake8 and mypy but pylint needs to remain with dashes separating the words.

Comment: I upvoted this answer in the past so it might have had its merit, however it misleads a user in https://github.com/pylint-dev/pylint/issues/9444#issue-2140604441. It's not true all the time, 28 can be achieved with any combination of Refactor, Warning and Convention messages raised by pylint without any error not fatal, not only if your configuration is faulty, see the other anwer for details.